# Add count till it reaches certain percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, percentage

I need to calculate how many more tickets i need to meet the target percentage. Let me try to explain with an example.

Lets assume I have below data - 
Tickets Met - 27
Tickets Missed - 3
Total Tickets - 30
Met % - 90%
Target % - 95%

So i want to know how many more tickets should i met to reach 95% (where my missed count will not change)

Comment: I am looking for a excel formula for the above scenario.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest following below formula:

Lets assume **Tickets_to_be_met = x**,

> `x = (0.95 * Total_Tickets) - Current_Tickets`

My formula is based on simple Maths(Percentage) calculation:

Considering your example: ((27 + x) / 30) * 100 = 95

where

27 = Current_Tickets,
30 = Total_Tickets

**EDIT**

> In Excel,

Try using `=((95*B1)-(A1*100))/5` Where B column contains Total_tickets and A column contains Current_tickets

Considering the Formula: `(27 + x) / (30 + x) = 95 / 100`

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks firoz for your response. I know the Mathematical calculation, how should we do it in excel using a formula is my question.

Comment: Well, I have also specified it, which i tried using some dummy data

Comment: If I put your formula in the given scenario, i will get result as 1.5 (0.95*30-27). This is not the result i m looking for because if i add 1.5 to Count of met tickets then it will be 28.5 and total will 31.5 and Met percentage will be 90.5%, but I wan to add that number which can help reaching at 95%. If i calculate manually, I will need additional 3 more Met tickets, then my total Met will be 57 (27+30) and count of total tickets will be 60, so 57/60 will give me 95% result. I want to knw the excel formula that can help me calculating that additional ticket count under met.

Comment: I have updated my answer, please let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know your total tickets and current tickets met
Total tickets: 30
Tickets met: 27

You want to additionally add tickets such that your tickets met is 95% of total tickets

```
 (Current_tickets_met + x)/(Total_tickets + x) = 95%
  (27+x)/(30+x) = 95/100
  This resolves x to be of value 30
```

Which means, if you additionally add 30 tickets

Current tickets met = 27+30 = 57
Total tickets met = 30+30 = 60

And 57/60 = 95%

Comment: Hi Hari, I want to know how many more (additional) tickets should be added to "Tickets Met" to reach 95%, where my "Ticket Missed" count will not change.

Comment: With your calculation, it will be, Tickets Met - 29 (27+2), Tickets Missed - 3, Total Tickets - 32(30+2), Met % - 90.6%

Comment: Updated the answer, I'm not sure if I'm understanding the question accurately. Do let me know if that's what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi Hari, yes this is what I need and thats a mathematical calculation... but i want to know How can i put this calculation in excel using formula..?